# Помогите визуализировать класс с помощью DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Имеется несколько простых классов

```
public class man {
   public string Name {get; set;}
}
public class street {
  public string StName {get;set;}
  public ObservableCollection<man> Men{get; set;}
}
 public class city {
  public string CityName {get;set;}
  public ObservableCollection<street> Streets {get; set;}
}`
```

Т.е. город включает улицы, они включают жителей. Еще один класс - коллекция городов

С помощью трех DataGrid хочу визуализировать связанные списки - при выборе города в первом, во втором показываются его улицы и далее в третьем жители.
Нужно ли в классах городов и улиц реализовывать методы возврата улиц и жителей соответсвенно для привязки к DataGrid или можно оставить свойства(имеет ли вообще это значение для использования в wpf)
Нужно ли вводить какое-то свойство для обозначения выбранного города и улицы?
Как уведомлять Textbox о том что изменилось имя жителя? Для коллекций все понятно - ObserveableCollection

Comment: `С помощью трех DataGrid` - вложенных друг в друга или отдельных? `Для коллекций все понятно - ObserveableCollection` - а для свойств INPC.

Comment: DataGrid - отдельные

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну допустим у нас есть некая коллекция с нужными данными:

```
public ObservableCollection<city> Cities { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<city>
    {
        new city
        {
            CityName = "Москва",
            Streets = new ObservableCollection<street>
            {
                new street
                {
                    StName = "Бабаевская улица",
                    Men = new ObservableCollection<man>
                    {
                        new man{Name = "Вася"},
                        new man{Name = "Петя"},
                        new man{Name = "Маша"}
                    }
                },
                new street
                {
                    StName = "Ткацкая улица",
                    Men = new ObservableCollection<man>
                    {
                        new man{Name = "Егор"},
                        new man{Name = "Катя"}
                    }
                },
                new street
                {
                    StName = "Елецкая улица",
                    Men = new ObservableCollection<man>
                    {
                        new man{Name = "Оля"}
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        new city
        {
            CityName = "Санкт-Петербург",
            Streets = new ObservableCollection<street>
            {
                new street
                {
                    StName = "Амбарная улица",
                    Men = new ObservableCollection<man>
                    {
                        new man{Name = "Антон"}
                    }
                },
                new street
                {
                    StName = "Парадная улица",
                    Men = new ObservableCollection<man>
                    {
                        new man{Name = "Алена"}
                    }

                },
                new street
                {
                    StName = "Улица Тюшина",
                    Men = new ObservableCollection<man>
                    {
                        new man{Name = "Кто то..."}
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

Теперь как вывести все это в отдельные элементы? Все это можно реализовать простым View, добавив спискам, где пользователь что то выбирает свойство `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem = "true"`, это сделает автоматическое оповещение других привязанных контролов и те обновят свое содержимое.
Пример:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <DataGrid Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Cities}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"/>
    <DataGrid Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Cities/Streets}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"/>
    <DataGrid Grid.Column="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Cities/Streets/Men}"/>
</Grid>
```

Результат:

[image: Result]

Comment: Почему так просто? Как списки знают что они друг к другу привязаны?

Comment: @АлексейМайборода Это простая синхронизация вложенных коллекций, в тонкости работы не разбирался, но суть в том, что при выборе элемента контрол с `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem` оповещает другие привязанные контролы и те меняют свои значения. Что то мудрить не нужно, все сделали уже до нас..